# Palleted/Unique values rendering not displaying in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

I have a multi-band raster in the form of a GeoTIFF. The raster contains 4 bands. Band 2 has 27 unique values ranging from 151 - 281. I would like to display each value discreetly using the 'Paletted/Unique values' option in Band rendering. When I click 'classify' the correct values are displayed but when I apply and close the dialogue nothing is displayed in QGIS.

[image]

If I use 'Singleband Pseudocolor' it displays fine but I'd like to display discrete colours without having to go through each value and change the colour. What's going on here? Why is Paletted/Unique not working?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what happens if you remove the `Hue`->`Colorize` flag?
Is that raster the only layer in your project or are there overlying ones which could interfere?

Comment: @RafDouglas Removing the `Hue->Colorize` flag doesn't change anything. The raster is the only layer in the project. I should probably also mention that the 27 labels display correctly in the 'Layers' window after applying the rendering.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of the `'Singleband Pseudocolor` ?
I can't think of a reason for the "no-show" :)

Comment: @RafDouglas I edited my post to include the screenshot. I realised that this method doesn't display the correct discrete values as it just evenly spreads the values between the min and max.

Comment: The palleted/unique renderer works as expected for me... what version of QGIS do you have? Maybe a sample of your raster would be helpful...

Comment: @DavidP I'm using 3.4.4-Madeira. Here's a link to sample data: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/sinwedh8g04vxgd/Sample.tif?dl=0)

Comment: Hmm interesting, didn't work on that file. But if i add classification values from 0 (0,1,2,..etc), it shows some data on map. It has to do with values lookup, data type or something... strange. I can solve this by rearranging bands to new raster (rearrange band processing tool). There I chose band 2 only, output data type set to int16 and run. On that output, I was able to classify that raster as expected. Hope that helps.

Comment: Rearranging to one band works but it's not convenient for me to have seperate rasters. Interestingly if I rearrange all bands to Int16 (as a test), band 2 still does not display Paletted/Unique values. However the original raster sample displays correctly for @RafDouglas (see comments below) without rearranging. He is using 3.6.2 on docker. What version do you have? Maybe the version does make a difference. I tried with a new user profile as suggested by RafDouglas but this did not help.

Comment: @AdamG I have tested this on 3.6.0 on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: OK. Good to know. The problem didn't occur in 3.6.2 or 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the problem by installing the newest version of QGIS 3.6.3-Noosa. Whilst the problem itself had occurred in 3.4.4 and was replicated by @DavidP in 3.6.0, it did not occur in 3.6.2 or 3.6.3. This does not necesarily mean that the problem is specifically related to the version of QGIS but for me this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if your raster displays correctly when color-mapped using a continuum spectrum  (Linear interpolation) and not when using discrete values is because the values of the pixels are not comprised in the list of `Paletted/Unique Value` classified colors.

If you set:

```
151 -> pink
156 -> light brown
etc..
```

A pixel whose value is, for example, 151.01 or 153 (non of which are present in the `Paletted/Unique Value` list) does not have a color associated and will therefore not be represented at all.

If, instead, you choose `Singleband pseudocolor`, you can still assign the same ramp/list as above, but in this case intermediate values will be interpolated.
A pixel with a value of 151.01 will look pink, one valued  153 will have a color midway between ping and light-brown.
And most importantly, both will be represented.

Comment: That can't be the case as there are no values between those identified by rendering the band with unique values. The values in the band are days of year. There are no decimel values or values inbetween. I know the 27 values and selecting `Paletted/Unique values` renders the correct 27 values.

Comment: If using `Paletted/Unique values` renders correctly, then I don't understand the original question...

Comment: By "renders correctly" I mean that by clicking `Paletted/Unique values > Classify` the correct band values (i.e. the 27 DOY) appear in the symbology window and in the layers window. However, as per my original question, the polygons do not display in QGIS. It's as if QGIS knows what I want it do and does everything it's supposed to do up until displaying the polygons. I edited my original post to include a screenshot of the empty display with the correctly labelled layers window.

Comment: I see, thanks. If you revert to the B/W or `Singleband pseudocolor`, then sample the raster with the `Identify Features` tool (the arrow with the "info" icon) on `Band 2` do you see the same values as the one in the classification? or slightly different ones?

Comment: I see the same values i.e. Each value is one from the list of 27.

Comment: would you mind/are you allowed to share the file? or even better, file + `.qgs` ?

Comment: I shared a sample of the file in a reply to @DavidP above. Here's a link to the `.qgs`: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/oylxxmhzfsyghvp/Sample.qgs?dl=0)

Comment: The qgs you linked renders the raster in multiband. However, I imported the raster, and `Paletted/Unique values` works on my computer. Try the `.qgs` here: https://we.tl/t-TuDjxkLHig
If it works, please share your non-working `.qgs` so we can compare a post a solution to the benefit of future users.

Comment: Screenshot of the working "paletted" render: https://we.tl/t-iRqeKOvkWJ

Comment: The `.qgs` you sent opens with the correct band and values in the layers window but still no polygons are displayed. Interestingly I've noticed that if I select Band 1 and `Paletted/Unique values > Classify` then the polygons display correctly but none of Bands 2, 3 or 4 display. Obviously it works for you so this must be a local issue. What do you suggest? Re-install QGIS? Are you also using 3.4.4?

Comment: I am using 3.6.2 on docker, but the version should hardly make a difference..
before reinstalling, you could create a new user on your PC (i.e. with blank QGIS preferences), log in as that user, and trying to display the raster.

Comment: I tried the new user idea but this did not work. @DavidP (see comments above) could not get band 2 to display `Paletted/Unique values` as you did. Maybe this is related to version after all? I will try re-installing in any case and see what happens.

Comment: I installed 3.6.3-Noosa and it works fine, the unique values are displaying as they should. It seems to me like this was an issue related to version 3.4.4 but I'd be interested to hear which version @DavidP is using.